# How can I be notified [eg via email] for any change in my AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an AWS account that use multiple devs and teams [dev/qa/mobile].
I would like to be notified when any change takes place in my AWS account.

For example a dev launches a new instance , or a new open port is added in a security group etc and he forgets to announce it to me or the rest of the team.

I want to be fully informed for these changes in order to apply specific architecture and/or security and people tend to mess with them.

Is there any dashboard or service inside AWS that I can customise it?

Someone suggested that I should take a look in CloudTrail. 
Has anyone done something like this?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/07/10/introducing-amazon-cloudwatch-logs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to go is to use cloudtrail with cloudwatch logs. In AWS [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/faqs/):

Q:What are the benefits of CloudTrail integration with CloudWatch Logs?

This integration enables you to receive SNS notifications of API activity captured by CloudTrail. For example, you can create CloudWatch alarms to monitor API calls that create, modify and delete Security Groups and Network ACL’s. For examples, go to the examples section of the user guide.

Based on SNS, you can then send email through SES

Comment: Hmmm, ok . I thought that there would be something more ready-made , but I can live with that. So , every action in AWS corresponds to an API call ? So if someone adds a new port in a sec group that opens the EC2 instance to the world I will be notified ?

Comment: that s pretty much true: one action = one API call (or several ones sometimes). if somebody opens a port in a security group it will be logged in cloudtrail, and if you configured an alarm in cloudwatch you will get notified. You could also have a look at AWS tools like trusted advisor or external tools like alertlogic for example

Answer (score 0):

I think the easier way is to use Amazon Cloudtrail service.

Cloudtrail logs any API call which is made on your AWS account. Every operation done on AWS is and API call (including instances operations as you have requested)

Here you can find more information about it

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/configure-cloudtrail-to-send-notifications.html

I hope this helps somehow.

Comment: I think that the problem in that case is that you receive a notification for EACH API call and you will end up with a lot of notifications. By using cloudwatch logs you can filter nicely which notifications should trigger an email or not

Answer (score -1):

You can find logs of your AWS account in S3,
Find below path in S3:
s3://security-logging/AWS_/AWSLogs/AWS Account no./CloudTrail/your region/year

You can also integrate CloudTrail with SQS to send notifications.

Comment: this depends if you have enabled cloudtrail and where you send its logs

Comment: I'm considering it as an example.